# Find Selected Feature in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis

I'm familiar with how to select a feature by highlighting it in the attribute table, but can you do the reverse? Click a feature on the map, and have it become highlighted in the attribute table?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Figured out that using "identify" does not highlight the feature in the attribute table, but "select features" does. Subtle difference, but an important one.